# Como Garbage Collection é implementado em Go?

Tags: garbage-collector, golang

Em [Golang](http://golang.org/) vi que esta linguagem é compilada (e é mesmo, o próprio website diz para quais arquiteturas os compiladores geram código), e, para minha surpresa, é Garbage Collected!

Garbage Collection é praticamente que universal no mundo das linguagens de VM e interpretadas.

E a implementação desses algorítimos de coleta de lixo é óbvio: O interpretador/VM implementa algorítimos para coleta de memória alocada; isto é possível porque a execução do programa está dentro da execução de outro programa independente que cuida da memória.

Mas numa linguagem compilada, o programa está "solto": Ele roda independentemente.

Então, sem um runtime wrapper, como Golang implementa Garbage Collection?

**Edit 1**

Bom, a grosso modo, o que eu entendi das respostas foi:

Go não tem um runtime para garbage collection, mas tem um runtime "companheiro": O GC é implementado como uma biblioteca standard da implementação da linguagem. Todo programa escrito e compilado em Go roda independentemente, mas ao lado dele há um outro runtime para a memória.

Comment: Não tenho muita autoridade sobre isso, então não vou responder, mas não tem segredo. Se uma alocação falha, o GC é invocado. De uma certa forma o GC é apenas uma parte da lib (isso é uma simplificação), e vai saber o que fazer. Eventualmente é possível disparar o GC em outros momentos, mas não é muito comum. Se for chamado em outros momentos, é as técnicas mais comuns são: em eventos específicos como timer ou alguma outra ação que faça sentido ou ainda chamadas manuais ao GC em algoritmos que faça sentido sua chamada. Mas duvido que vá além da alocação de memória que dispare ele. Idem em VM.

Comment: Também não sou especialista em Go, mas li dois textos com informações bem interessantes e relavantes a respeito tanto de GC quanto sobre gerenciamento de memória em geral: 

Link 1:
http://blog.cloudflare.com/recycling-memory-buffers-in-go

Link 2:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7823725/what-kind-of-garbage-collection-does-go-use

Comment: Você pode dar uma olhada em: http://code.google.com/p/go/source/browse/src/pkg/runtime/mgc0.c

Comment: Interessante notar que a partir da versão 1.5, o GC de Go roda juntamente com as outras goroutines da runtime, e por no máximo 10ms a cada 40ms. Foi um aumento de performance considerável em relação a implementações anteriores.

Answer (score 12):

Segundo a [FAQ da linguagem](http://golang.org/doc/faq#garbage_collection), Go usa um coletor paralelo [*mark-and-sweep*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29#Na.C3.AFve_mark-and-sweep).

O algoritmo básico é o mesmo usado no Java, porém em paralelo para melhor desempenho, consistindo em varrer o "grafo" de objetos e marcando os objetos que são referenciados de alguma forma com uma *flag*. Após percorrer todas as referências, os objetos que não estão marcados podem ser removidos da memória.

Considere a animação:

[image: Algoritmo Mark-and-sweep]

Segundo uma [resposta do SOEN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7823725/what-kind-of-garbage-collection-does-go-use) a versão 1.3 da linguagem Go irá implementar um coletor concorrente para melhorar em menores pausas de processamento. Ainda segundo esta referência, o coletor do Go possui nas seguintes características:

- ***Non-generational***: não usa essa abordagem que considera a "idade" do objeto.
- ***Non-compacting***: não move os objetos para reorganizar a memória alocada.
- ***Non-precise*** (Não preciso): podem ocorrer falsos positivos ao "flegar" um objeto, devido a tipos variantes que podem ser ou não ponteiros para objetos.
- ***Stop-the-world***: interrompe completamente a execução do programa enquanto é executado.
- ***Weak references***: não suporta referências "fracas", isto é, que não impedem o coletor de limpar o objeto.

Para concluir, o fato da linguagem ser compilada na verdade não influencia na mesma ter a capacidade de ter ou não um coletor de lixo dos objetos instanciados. Essa ideia de que linguagens dinâmicas tem os objetos "soltos" é só uma impressão, pois por debaixo dos panos tudo o que a JVM faz são chamadas à API do C++ para alocar e desalocar a memória.

O ponto é o preço a ser pago por este tipo de facilidade. Os desenvolvedores da linguagem Go afirmam claramente que foi uma decisão tomada com base no ganho de produtividade e na diminuição da complexidade de implementação, principalmente no que se refere à programação que envolve concorrência.

Answer (score 4):

Programas escritos em linguagem Go, apesar de compilados, vão ter os recursos requeridos pela especificação embutidos no executável gerado.

A linguagem vai ser compilada assim como C, C++, Rust, etc, ou seja, diretamente para o código de máquina e não para um bytecode intermediário para ser executado por uma VM (que proveria GC por exemplo). A diferença com C e C++ é que este executável vai ter embutido em si todos os recursos para que não só GC funcione, mas também as goroutines, os channels etc.

Imagine programar C com GC, [isto é possível sabia](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6679)? Existem bibliotecas de GC para uso em linguagem C, no final o mesmo binário compilado de sempre, nada de bytecodes, só uma mera biblioteca. Go meio que faz isso pra você por debaixo dos panos.

O mesmo se dá com Rust (especificamente o caso de GC, ainda não, num futuro provável).

Quanto à implementação/técnologia do GC, defiro a explicação pra documentação com uma nota sobre a utilização de [escape analysis](https://web.archive.org/web/20160923043317/https://scvalex.net/posts/29/) que é algo interessante, em questão de performance, de se ter ciência mesmo num ambiente GC.

Comment: O coletor de lixo em algumas linguagens, como em Java ou C#, costumam ter um impacto que pode ser significativo na execução da aplicação. Porém, o mesmo não parece o ocorrer na linguagem Rust. Isso é verdade? Ou Rust também "paga um preço" em desempenho?

Comment: @DanOver Na época desta questão, Rust ainda tinha intenções de suportar GC nativamente via ponteiros GC especiais (`@`), o que foi [totalmente abandonado](https://web.archive.org/web/20141229071311/https://pcwalton.github.io/blog/2013/06/02/removing-garbage-collection-from-the-rust-language/) depois que o caminho para a linguagem mudou totalmente para focar em performance com segurança e concorrer com C e C++.

Comment: @DanOver se Rust tivesse aderido ao GC convencional, pagaria o preço como todo mundo que adere tem que pagar, mas o Rust de hoje passa longe disso, então não tem o que pagar nesse assunto.