# impacto de uma memoria heap alta na JVM

Tags: java, garbage-collector

Qual é o impacto de se ter uma alta memória heap na JVM? O Garbage collector demora mais para limpar a memória quando esta é muito alta (por volta de 12gb)? Caso sim, existe algum modo de evitar esta demora programáticamente, sem utilizar soluções de infraestrutura?

Comment: Não há como prever quando o GC entra em ação, apenas confie nele. Java é uma linguagem de alto nível, a intenção é justamente não pensar em memória e coisas do tipo.

Comment: Eu sei disso, meu problema é que suspeito que a demora do sistema em alguns momentos é relacionado a atividade do GC limpando a memória heap. O Tamanho da memória impacta neste processo? Esta é minha dúvida...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O tamanho da memória vai impactar no tempo de execução do Garbage Collector, mas não diretamente. O tempo vai depender da quantidade de objetos alocados.

O GC percorre todas as referências e marca os objetos que ainda estão referenciados. Os objetos que sobrarem estarão disponíveis para coletagem. Entretanto, o GC não roda imediatamente para cada objeto desalocado.

Não tenho um benchmark sobre isso. Porém, utilizo diariamente um Eclipse com um máximo de 2GB de memória o qual eu nunca fecho porque o computador é hibernado. Dificilmente ele passa de 1GB, pois os objetos desalocados são coletados antes que a memória aumente muito. Assim, embora a quantidade máxima seja bem maior, não sinto os efeitos de um um GC rodando com a memória cheia.

No seu caso, pode haver problemas se algo próximo dos 12 GB forem usados e muita memória for alocada e desalocada constantemente, obrigando o GC a rodar várias vezes.

Porém não é possível prever sem saber a natureza da aplicação e a sua arquitetura. Até porque pode-se usar diferentes técnicas para forçar o GC a executar mais ou menos, por exemplo manter variáveis em chache estático.

Veja mais sobre o funcionamento do GC na minha [resposta à *Como Garbage Collection é implementado em Go?*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/14239/227)